# Time series database - interpolation and filtering

Tags: filter, time-series, interpolation, influxdb

Does any existing time series database contain functionality for interpolation and digital filtering for outlier detection (Hampel, Savitzky-Golay)? Or at least provide interfaces to enable custom query result post-processing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know InfluxDB does not offer you anything more than a simple [linear interpolation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill) and the basic set of [InfluxQL functions](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/functions/).

Looks like, everything more complex than that has to be done by hand with the programming language of your choice. Influx has a number of language clients.

There is [an article](https://prometheus.io/blog/2015/06/18/practical-anomaly-detection/) on anomaly detection with Prometheus, but that looks like an attempt rather then a capability.

However, there is a thing called Kapacitor for InfluxDB. It a quite powerful data processing tools which allows define User Defined Functions (UDF). Here is an article of how to implement [custom anomaly detection](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.4/guides/anomaly_detection/) with Kapacitor.

Answer (score 0):

[Akumuli time-series database](https://github.com/akumuli/Akumuli) provides some basic outlier detection, for instance the EWMA and SMA. You can issue a query that will return the difference between the predicted value (given by EWMA or SMA) and the actual value.